# Is mongodb update with query atomic?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, concurrency, updates

`mongodb` write and update opertaions are atomic, as stated in their [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).

But does it also atomic when using query?

For example:

```
db.collection.update( { id : 1 , count : 0 } , { $inc : { count : 1 } } )
```

If I execute this operation in a multi threaded environment, is it possible that at some point the value of `count` in the document with `id` equal to 1 will be greater than 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any modification to a single document is atomic.

Using your example, let's say there are two threads trying to update that document using the same query:

```
Thread A: db.collection.update({_id: 1, count: 0}, {$inc: {count: 1}})
Thread B: db.collection.update({_id: 1, count: 0}, {$inc: {count: 1}})
```

with the collection containing the document:

```
collection: {_id: 1, count: 0}
```

If thread `A` managed to update the document before thread `B`, the collection would then contain:

```
collection: {_id: 1, count: 1}
```

Thread `B` will search for a document matching `_id:1, count:0` but since that document was already modified by thread `A`, the update in thread `B` will not proceed (since the document no longer "exists" as thread `B` is concerned).

In other words, thread `A` will return `nMatched: 1, nModified: 1`, and thread `B` will return `nMatched: 0, nModified: 0`.

To specifically answer your question, there will not be a case where a document `{_id: 1, count: 2}` will exist.

Comment: But mongodb doesn't lock on reads, so isn't it possible that both the thread will read the unmodified document (with the specified query) and then update it (write) one after the other?

Comment: No, the `update` command will ensure that the update condition is true before it applies the update. Also, if the two threads happened to try to write to the same document at the same time, one of them will get the `WriteConflict` exception and will transparently retry. This retry will not succeed since the update condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: Ok thank you, can you give some official doc to back this answer? I couldn't find any...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no explicit mention of this behaviour in the docs, but it is implied since an update is mentioned to be atomic, and an update must match the query part of the `update()` query. The behaviour you're describing would imply that the `db.collection.update()` method is broken and would update a document even though the query part of the `update()` statement is not true.

Comment: This answer is correct. The "update operation on single document is atomic" means that selection and modification occur as an atomic operation. This is mentioned in book _"MongoDB in Action" 2nd Edition, Ch - 7 Updates, atomic operations, and deletes, pg. 168_ (first line). 
Just to provide more information on update operations, in case of upsert=true we need to take care as mentioned in [update-with-unique-indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-unique-indexes)

Comment: I know it's difficult to trust a tutorial site for its accuracy of information but this [site](https://tutorialseye.com/mongodb-atomic-operations.html) also supports this answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the documentation, **atomicity is not mentioned** about `db.collection.update` *with query*.

instead `findAndModify()` have mentioned with atomic behavior.

`db.myCollection.findAndModify( { query: { ...},update: {....}})`

refrence [findAndUpdate doc link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#concurrency-control).